# Appending parameter to URL to solve issue with Page Caching and Tax Toggles

Tags: wordpress, caching, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce website which uses a plugin called "Booster for WooCommerce" primarily for their "Tax Display" module. This plugin enables us to have a button in the header which allows the customer to switch between inc and exc VAT. The default setting is including tax.

The problem I'm encountering now is when I enable page caching in W3 Total Cache, the plugin is caching the first visit to a shop or product page along with the prices and then the next person to visit that page sees pricing based on the first user's tax toggle setting, not their own.

I can think of a few solutions to this in varying complexity but after noticing that the booster plugin sets a session variable via:

```
WC()->session->set('wcj_toggle_tax_display',( 'incl' === $current_value ? 'excl' : 'incl' ));
```

I'm wondering if there's a simple fix where I could simply hook in just before page load and if that session variable is set to excl, then set a URL parameter such as "?vat=false". Which I'm assuming would then cache as it's own unique URL and solve the problem.

I'm just not sure which hook would work for appending the parameter to the URL and my searches are getting me nowhere.

I've scoured over various solutions to this issue for days now, so a simple fix like this would be a godsend, I'm just not 100% sure how possible it is.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 0):

So far, the following code seems to have solved this problem but I'm still testing further with W3 Total Cache.

```
// Add URL parameter vat=false if tax toggle set to excl
function custom_redirect_append_url_params() {
    if (is_woocommerce()) {
        $toggle_status = wcj_session_get( 'wcj_toggle_tax_display' );
        if (empty($toggle_status)) $toggle_status = 'incl'; //default value = incl
        
        //if vat isn't set as a query var && toggle status is set to excl then redirect
        if(!isset($_GET['vat']) && $toggle_status === 'excl') {
            //do your redirect here with wp_redirect()
            wp_redirect( add_query_arg( 'vat', 'false', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ));
            exit; //prevent wordpress continuing to load templates
        }
        elseif($_GET['vat'] === 'false' && $toggle_status === 'incl') {
            wp_redirect( add_query_arg( 'vat', 'true', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ));
            exit; //prevent wordpress continuing to load templates
        }
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect','custom_redirect_append_url_params');
```